# JavaScript relative AJAX call path

Tags: javascript, relative-path, include-path

I have a script containing PHP and JavaScript files.
All these files are in the root folder `/myfolder`.

Let's say the script I have to include on my website is `/myfolder/script.js` , the problem is that in `script.js` I have ajax calls to `../myfolder/ajax.php`, which, because the path will be relative to the page the script is included won't work if I had something like this on the page `/a/b/page.php`:

`<script src="../../myfolder/script.js><script>` because this will call the ajax method from `../myfolder/ajax.php` as stated in the AJAX call, which in this case is `/a/myfolder/ajax.php`.

How can I rewrite the AJAX call URL so that it will always point to the right file regardless where the `script.js` is included?

```
ROOT
|---myfolder
    |--script.js
    |--ajax.php
|--page1.php
|--subfolder
   |--page2.php
   |--subfolder
      |--page3.php
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `ajax.php`?

Comment: That will call `/a/b/ajax.php` which is not the correct path.

Comment: Could you provide a simple graphic representation of your folder/file structure? I'm getting headaches trying to grasp this in text form.

Comment: @MCL, sure, it confuses me too.

Comment: Done. This should work if script.js is included from any page.php.

Comment: Afaik, the location of the script itself should be irrelevant. Since it gets executed by another page, that page's url should be the base for relative URLs. Have you tried calling `'myfolder/ajax.php'` from `page1.php`?

Comment: If I call that from a subfolder won't the resulting path be `subfolder/myfolder/ajax.php` ?

Comment: From the first subfolder, it should be `'../myfolder/ajax.php'`; from the second `'../../myfolder/ajax.php'`

Comment: epoch's comment is good. If I simply write `/myfolder/ajax.php` this will access myfolder from the root and should work.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/**
 * returns the current context path,
 * ex: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Controller returns /MyApp/
 * ex: http://localhost:8080/MyApp returns /MyApp/
 * ex: https://www.example.co.za/ returns /
 */
function getContextPath() {
    var ctx = window.location.pathname,
        path = '/' !== ctx ? ctx.substring(0, ctx.indexOf('/', 1) + 1) : ctx;
    return path + (/\/$/.test(path) ? '' : '/');
}
```

---

on a URL like `http://www.example.com/ajax`:

```
getContextPath() + 'myfolder/ajax.php'
```

will return `/ajax/myfolder/ajax.php`

---

similarly on a URL like `http://www.example.com/`:

```
getContextPath() + 'myfolder/ajax.php'
```

will return `/myfolder/ajax.php`

---

lastly on a URL like `http://www.example.com/myfolder/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/`:

```
getContextPath() + 'myfolder/ajax.php'
```

will return `/myfolder/ajax.php`

Comment: Yes, but I need it to return `../myfolder/ajax.php` . So in every case the script has to return a relative path to `/myfolder` which is in the root folder. If the current page URL has a depth of 3 (has 3 parent-folders) the AJAX call should be done to `../../../myfolder.php` .

Comment: it does not need to be relative, by specifying `/` in front of the url you are calling; it runs from the root of the web address, so if you are on www.example.com and you make a call to `/ajax/ajax.php` the url that will be called is www.example.com/ajax/ajax.php

Comment: `myfolder.php` never changes location so it always has the same url, we are just building up the absolute url with the function

Comment: So I could simply replace in `script.js` the AJAX call url to be `/myfolder/ajax.php` ?

Comment: yes, _if your site is always running in the_ **root** context, if your app is located at `/MyApp/` then you need the function

Comment: Thanks, I had to add this code to make it work for me: `if (!ctx.endsWith('/')) {
            ctx += '/';
        }`